# Scientific calculator that can expands polynomial like $(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-3)$

Tags: calculator

Is there a scientific calculator that can expands a polynomal like $(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-3)$? Any scientific calculator like Texas Instruments can do that?

Comment: Yes: [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) is a powerful free computer algebra system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally been using [Archimedes Calculator](http://www.archimedescalculator.com/) as a teacher that wants to periodically come up with polynomials *on the spot* for my students to factor. I've been using it for over a year now and it has done everything I need it to.